# What is the best way to call SOAP web service with Android?

Tags: android, web-services, soap

I need some advices.
I've a `WSDL` and I need to call some services.

For you, What is the best way to call`SOAP web service` with Android?
I know that we can:

- use the library `Ksoap 2`
- create `xml` templates and send them by a simple `http protocol`.
- Or i can do something like:

```
  public class AppelService {
```

private static final String NAMESPACE = "http://my-website.com";
  private static final String URL = "http://mon-example-web-services/wsdl.WSDL";
  private static final String SOAP_ACTION = "getWeather";
  private static final String METHOD_NAME = "getWeather";

  private String getWeather(String city) {

    try {
      SoapObject request = new SoapObject(NAMESPACE, METHOD_NAME);
      request.addProperty("city", city);

      SoapSerializationEnvelope envelope = new SoapSerializationEnvelope(SoapEnvelope.VER11);
      envelope.setOutputSoapObject(request);

      AndroidHttpTransport androidHttpTransport = new AndroidHttpTransport(URL);
      androidHttpTransport.call(SOAP_ACTION, envelope);

    } catch (Exception e) {
      Log.e("getWeather", "", e);
    }
  }
}

From your own experience, what do you think is the best way to do it ?

any help is appreciated.
Thanks.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I would definitely advocate using [ksoap2-android libary](http://code.google.com/p/ksoap2-android/). I have done this very research, and nothing beats using this library in terms of versatility.
The code you have provided is ksoap2.

From the ksoap2-android website:

> The ksoap2-android project provides a lightweight and efficient SOAP
>   library for the Android platform.
>
> It is a fork of the kSOAP2 library that is tested with the Android
>   platform in mind. It also has a bunch of more features and
>   enhancements and takes in bug fixes and contributions and releases
>   regularly. It is also easily available for Maven and Ant users alike.

Answer (score 1):

I personally use ksoap2-android because it is pretty straightforward for parsing response object...
If you are comfortable with it, ,why would you use something else ?

A bientôt ;)

Edit : I mean ksoap2 **-android** of course